# Fullcalendar how load BusinessHours from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

When i try to load my businessHours from php 
i get [image]

but when I paste manually in businessHours the JSON returned by PHP it work fine.
[image]

json is:

```
[ 
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[0]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"19:00:00"
   },
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[1]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"10:00:00"
   },
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[2]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"10:00:00"
   },
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[3]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"14:00:00"
   },
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[4]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"14:00:00"
   },
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[5]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"14:00:00"
   },
   { 
      "daysOfWeek":"[6]",
      "startTime":"09:00:00",
      "endTime":"19:00:00"
   }
]
```

I don't know what is wrong.
my JS code is: `businessHours:  { url: 'classes/load-orariapertura.php' }` 
PHP code is: https://pastebin.com/M9yL9DQn

Comment: What's wrong is that `businessHours` does not recognise or accept a URL. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours - it can be boolean / object / array. The object definition does not allow for a URL. You're probably thinking of event sources where that can be done. If you want to load the data from PHP you would have to inject it into the JS with `<?php echo json_encode ... ?>` or, fetch it from AJAX _before_ you load the calendar, and pass the downloaded data to the calendar as an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with: `businessHours:  <?php include_once('classes/load-orariapertura.php'); ?>`

PHP page return Array encoded in JSON.